# WebSphere 7 + WebSphere Deployer Plugin

Tags: jenkins, websphere-7

I just have a quick question. By following set up guide it is all good until the artifact update. I copied all required *.jar* files and imported )cacerts_. I can test the connection web sphere (I am using WS 7). All is working fine. But when plugin reach a step to check application installed on WS I am getting the following error:

Any ideas?

```
-------------------------------------------
Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...
The following artifacts will be deployed in this order...

-------------------------------------------
XXX_123.ear
-------------------------------------------

Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.DeploymentServiceException: Could not determine if artifact 'XXX' is installed: javax.management.ObjectName cannot be cast to javax.management.ObjectName
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.isArtifactInstalled(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:357)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.stopArtifact(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:243)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:198)

at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)

at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)

at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)

at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)

at 
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)

at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)

at hudson.matrix.MatrixRun.run(MatrixRun.java:146)

at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)

at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)

Build step 'Deploy To IBM WebSphere Application Server' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.  As this looks like a classloader issue, I dig aroung for classloading specification in jenkins.

I ended up updating the PluginFirstClassLoader property in the plugin and my deployment now complete succesfully.

To do this change, edit the file ﻿:

```
    $USER_HOME/.jenkins/plugins/websphere-deployer/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Then replace the following property :

```
    PluginFirstClassLoader: true
```

By

```
    PluginFirstClassLoader: false
```

My current setup :

- jenkins : 2.1-1.1
- websphere-deployer : 1.3.4

Comment: Great! This worked for me. My project uses JDK6 but Jenkins is running in JRE8. So It seems that with this setting it is forcing the plugin to use JDK6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you got IBM jars needed by plugin from WAS 7 they are compiled for a jvm 6: Jenkins uses java 7 (at least my version), so I guess incompatible java bytecode rises.
I copied IBM jars from a WAS 8 installation and all went ok.
Hope this helps.